# Select an image form datebase and resize it

Tags: php

The code below will resize an image to 50*50 but whenever i select the name of the image in my database and put it like these $filename = 'folder/$imagename'; it does not work how can i fix these.

```
    <?php
$filename = 'folder/Aizen.jpg';

$width = 50;
$height = 50;

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($filename);

$ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
   $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
} else {
   $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
}

$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
?>
<img src="<?= $filename ?>" alt="" />
```

Comment: you have to define "doesn't work"

Comment: "it does not work" is not a very verbose error description. Maybe the images in the path "folders/..." do not exist? Maybe you need to adjust the path?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

/*
Database Query
*/

$myImageFromTableData = $row['Image'];

/*
Start my Code
*/

$filename = $myImageFromTableData;
```

Just one small issue. You have not shown your database code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use variables in single quote strings. Try it like this.

```
$filename = 'folder/'.$imagename;
```